# is there a gem used to store rails logs in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, logging

I finally have my application written, and now I have a request to store the logs into a mysql db for later searching. Any ideas besides log4r?

Thanks!
Tonya

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving from apache you could use mod_log_sql

http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-logging-to-a-mysql-database-with-mod_log_sql-on-debian-etch